# Why is Golang json.Unmarshall not working with "e" and "E" properties?

Tags: json, go

Suppose we want to unmarshal the JSON string `{"e": "foo", "E": 1}`.

Unmarshalling using the type `messageUppercaseE` works like expected. When using the type `message` though, the error `json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field message.e of type string` is returned.

1. Why are we not able to unmarshal the JSON, if only the `"e"` struct tag is present?
2. How would I be able to unmarshal the JSON? (I know that I am able to do this via [Jeffail/gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs), but would like to stick to the type based approach.)

```
type message struct {
    EventType string `json:"e"`
}

type messageUppercaseE struct {
    EventType  string `json:"e"`
    UppercaseE uint64 `json:"E"`
}
```

Try it yourself at https://play.golang.org/p/T6KMJRLy7TN

Comment: Feels pretty annoying to me... Do you see potential for improving the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the docs for unmarshal:

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match.

In this case, it is the case-insensitive match that causes the trouble.